# Finding Z(g) where g = $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $ in $ GL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Finding $Z(g)$ where g = $$\begin{pmatrix}    1 & 5  \\ 0 & 1   \end{pmatrix} $$ in $$ GL_2(\mathbb{R})$$
The centralizer $Z(g)$ of an element $g$ in $G$ is the set of elements which commute with $g$.

So far, my thought is that $d \times I$ with $d$ is not zero is in $Z(g)$. This is because any element in the center commute with every element in the group. So it commutes with $g$.

But I don't know how to find any other matrices that satisfy the requirement.
I don't think I can find it by hand one by one. Is there any trick I can use to find such matrices?

Comment: powers of $g$ also commute with $g$

Comment: When you're stuck doing it by hand is the only way you'll gain intuition. Set up the matrix equation with an arbitrary matrix being multiplied on both sides.

Comment: ah I see. just basic method.

Comment: Solve $\pmatrix{1&5\\0&1}\pmatrix{x&y\\z&t}=\pmatrix{x&y\\z&t}\pmatrix{1&5\\0&1}$ for $x$, $y$ etc. It's just a bunch of linear equations.